# Scrollable table with a changing tbody using ace:datatable

Tags: css, jsf, icefaces

I have a ace:dataTable component, it's scrollable. The problem is that when it is scrollable, the body is shifted relative to the header if the data in it has been changed. How can i solve this problem? 
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU32c.jpg)

Comment: Please can you post what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to change the rules (display:none on display:table-header-group; and add visibility:collapse) for hidden thead, tried to get a static width. Work correctly only a turn off scrollbar on component.

Comment: If you don't post your CSS that's not possible to be guessed.

Comment: It's not my css. Css rules for table has generated by a component. I do not add any rules from myself

Comment: A simple example that I did. There is also an incorrect scrolling (attached snapshot in the main post). http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=ace:dataTable&exp=Scrolling

Comment: @XtremeBiker My question can be shortened to "How to initiate ajax which will reload the table". Because the table is rebuilt if ajax works on a choice, sorting, etc. But what specifically to choose so that it redraws the table after each resizing in the field I do not understand